# get Vertices from Vertex Buffer Handle

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Is it possible to somehow retrive the vertices of an object from the Vertex Buffer Handle ?
I'm using OpenGL.

If it is possible how is this done.

Answer (score 2):

In a desktop OpenGL application you can use glMapBuffer to retrieve a pointer to the vertices stored in a vbo.  However, this method is not required according to the ES 2.0 spec, section 2.9.

Comment: Is there any magical way of retrieving the vertices of a modelled object using Opengl ES ?    I would like to loop through all the vertices and somehow get the size of my object in the World.

Comment: You had your vertices on the client side at some point when you called glBufferData(), you should be able to use that data to find the size.

Comment: and if you are looking for them post-render you can us glReadPixels()